# Speedup calculation of the largest eigenvalue and eigenvector of a 400×400 matrix?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, numerics, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Actually, the matrix is an adjacency matrix of a network. The code is:

```
A1 = GridGraph[{20, 20}, PlotLabel -> "20*20 nodes", VertexLabels -> "Name"]
A = AdjacencyMatrix[A1];
```

I want to calculate the eigenvalue of A and its eigenvector.
I have tried the normal function such as `Eigenvalues` and `Eigenvectors`. But it need much time and may not get a result (my laptop have not complete the calculation yet.)

The code is:

```
λ = N[Eigenvalues[Normal[A], 1]][[1]];
uA = N[Eigenvectors[Normal[A], 1]][[1]];
```

I want to know whether there is a method or parameter to reduce the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that `AdjacencyMatrix` returns a non-real valued matrix

```
g = GridGraph[{20, 20}];
amg = AdjacencyMatrix[A1];
```

meaning the elements are all integers:

```
In[]:= Map[Head,Normal@amg,{2}]//Flatten//Union
Out[]= {Integer}
```

and the kernel is trying to find an answer in terms of integers, rational numbers, and roots. Numericizing **before** computation leads to the timings in fractions of a second for your example:

```
In[]:= eig = Eigensystem[N[amg]];//AbsoluteTiming
Out[]= {0.05914,Null}
```

Eigenvalues are ordered by the **absolute value** of the eigenvalues, so the first one is the max. You get it and its corresponding eigenvector as:

```
eig[[All, 1]]
```

Comment: yeah, using N to solve is much more quickly.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want the largest eigenvalue, the [Arnoldi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration) is much faster than calculating all eigenvalues (and associated eigenvectors) and picking the largest:

```
Eigensystem[A // N, 1,
            Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*    {0.007187, {{3.95532}, {{-0.00211558, -0.0041839, ..., -0.00211558}}}}    *)
```